# How to run Karate tests using maven with dynamic tags

Tags: java, karate, intuit-partner-platform

I want to execute Karate tests using maven and pass the tags dynamically to the execution. I'm using junit4 and i tried both of the approaches - parallel and simple with @RunWith annotation.

**@RunWith**

```
package karate;

import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:karate")
public class KarateTestIT {
}
```

Using this approach I'm able to pass the tags to the execution dynamically, but if the karate test fails the maven build is still successful.

**Parallel**

```
package karate;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class KarateTestIT {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:karate").tags().parallel(5);
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }
}
```

Using the parallel approach the maven build fails if the karate test fails. But I'm unable to pass the tags to the test via maven command options.

I'm running tests with command

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @tag"
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@tag"
```

Am I missing on something? Is there a way to achieve both dynamic tags and failure of maven build in case of karate test fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you ran into this bug: [Karate 0.9.5 : Can't get command line options in parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60412123/143475)

Can you try with 0.9.6.RC3 and confirm ?

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer :]. Yes it works with version 0.9.6.RC3 and parallel approach so i guess i will use it for now and after final 0.9.6 will be released i'll switch to it. Again, thank you for help :]